# Firestore data influenced by phone language

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, location

I am doing an app in flutter and when I change the language of the phone if affects my location. For example if my language of the phone is set in English , I only see the users that register to my app with English language set. If I change it to another language ( in the settings , let's say Romana) I only see people that registered in the app with that language set. There is any way I can make the location to be restricted only to English language? To not be affected by the users settings.

Comment: Not clear to me where you "only see the users that register [...] with English".  Is this in your app, or in the Firebase Console, or ... ?  Do your Firestore queries have any type of `.where()` that is driven by a language parameter (that your app injects)?

Comment: In my app user has to signup . If the phone in settings has the language set to English , this user will appear only for people that register with the same setting. If the user is signing up with other language , he can't see user 1

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/oYhC8DI

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We have no idea what your app does, what a "user" is, how they "sign up", where you see this data, etc.